# How to use miktex with texlive on manjaro linux?

Tags: miktex, texmaker, linux

I always used miktex on windows, but when I tried to migrate to manjaro linux, I couldn't. I installed miktex and then tried to install texmaker. It turns out that texmaker demands texlive, which seems to be incompatible with miktex on linux. (I.e. texlive cannot be installed if you already have miktex). What should I do? I don't want to use texlive

Comment: I don't understand why an editor should request a special texsystem (and if it would I would use another one). But why don't you want to use texlive? It is fine.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I don't understand it too. I think its an issue of manjaro package manager. About texlive, it works fine until you start writing non-english texts. In my case, it just always throws errors about some .sty files missing

Comment: There should be no difference between miktex and texlive, assuming that you have a current vanilla texlive (and not some outdated variant provided by your linux system). But to answer your question: try to install first texmaker and then miktex.

Comment: @TeXnician why not? There would be also texlive installed but you could then switch the pathes to point to miktex.

Comment: you can use either miktex or texlive but miktex on linux is very new and the overwhelming majority of tex users on linux use texlive. Whatever issues you have are local path and dependency setup that you could have with either system.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You are right, sorry. I missed that consequence.